# Bypass include-preclude for one file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am adding a popup page to my java spring mvc app (brief set of questionnaire questions on one page).  The application has an include-prelude and include-coda on *.jsp for the header and footer.  I would like to not include these on the popup.jsp page.  Is there a simple way to do this (other than move to an include on each page) ?   The only thing I have tried so far is to alter the suffix to jspf but this wasn't recognized by the MVC controller call.  I thought I'd see if there was a proper way to do it before carrying on with these 'hacky' approaches.

Thanks.

Comment: I've ended up using includes on all pages.  The only other option I could think of was to add a 2nd InternalResourceViewResolver to jspf and so I could resolve to these pages though the MVC controller as well, but not have a include-preclude on them.  This didn't work out so well although I didn't spend too long trying to get it to work so I won't say it isn't an option.